# Does fractional part converge in distribution to a uniform random variable?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-limit-theorems

Let $X$ be a continuous random variable with a density function $f(x).$ Let $\{x\}$ denote the fractional part of a real number. I am tryng to prove that 
$$
\mathbb{P}[\{nX\}\leq z] \rightarrow z, \ \ \forall z \in [0,1]
$$

Can anyone help me in this ?

My attempt:

If $g_n(z)$ is the density of $\{nX\}$, I got $g_n(z)=\sum_{m \in \mathbb{Z}}\frac{1}{n}f(\frac{m}{n}+\frac{z}{n})$. Can I justify from here ?

One can assume nice properties on $f$ if needed but I want to keep those assumptions as minimal as possible.

Comment: How nice does the term "continuous random variable" promise you that $f$ must be?

Comment: @HenningMakholm: You can assume nice properties on $f$ if needed.

Answer (score -2):

The obvious counterexample is the constant case $f(x) = \delta_{1/2}$ (for the Dirac $\delta$).  More generally, I doubt this is true of pathological continuous densities constructed, say, with peaks at all [dyadic rational numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyadic_rational).

If you specify extra smoothness then it may be true.

Comment: The Dirac delta is not really a function, though.